# Javascript library able to support big numbers whose exponent is also a big number

Tags: javascript, libraries, biginteger

I am looking for a Javascript library able to work with very, very, very big numbers (I only need a precision of a few digits after the decimal point so it should be possible) which is able to work with numbers of the form `5e+(7e+194)`  for example, and also print them in that form. Is there such a library out there? It would be extra sweet if it can handle as many e's as I give it (e.g. `1e+1e+...+1e+154`)

Comment: So what libraries did you try that did not work?

Comment: multiple e's? That is strange.

Comment: @epascarello I tried https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ but I could only get it to around 1e200000, since it calculated all the digits, it became very slow at that point.